# change "cache" name to "backup"

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have a Debian server, my partition `/dev/sda6` (which has a lot of space left) is mounted on `/cache`. I want to use this partition for file backup.

I want to change the name of `/cache` to `/backup`. When I tried to do this by `mv` it told me "Device or resource busy".
So how can I do it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate of *some* question here, it should be. Long story short, you unmount the file system, change the mount point, edit /etc/fstab, then mount the file system again. You can't change the mountpoint while the file system is mounted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a folder called `/backup`

Open `/etc/fstab`

Change mountpoint of `/dev/sda6` to `/backup`

Reboot

Confirm it is mounted at `/backup` by typing `mount` into a terminal.

Delete the other folder with `rmdir` (only deletes empty folders)

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

No need to Reboot.
Create a directory /backup

umount -lz /cache

edit /etc/fstab

vi /etc/fstab

and change the directory name

mount -t ext3 /dev/sda6 /backup

(ext3 or ext4 or any format of the drive)

or

mount -o remount /

Comment: This answer seems to be missing critical information on how to accomplish each step.  Consider adding that missing comment so the answer is complete.